# Difference between a[0,0] and a[0][0] in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please difference between a[0,0] and a[0][0] in multidimensional array javascript.
For example printing in chrome console:

> ### For a[0][0] in console

[image]

> ### For a[0,0] in console

[image]

Please anyone explain me what is a[0,0] do in javascript array

Comment: [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language syntax which is heavily documented elsewhere, not a specific programming problem

Comment: a[0,0] becomes a[0], a[1,0] becomes a[0]. when js evaluates 0,1 it returns the last numeric. for e.g 0,1,2,3 will be 3.

Comment: Thanks @BOSS this helped me now to differentiate a[0][0] and a[0,0]